# Android acess to native screen buffer from Java

Tags: android, screen, screen-capture

Is it possible, from within my android java app, to capture an image of what is on the screen, even if it was written using native (ndk)? I do not wish to take screen shots of other apps, just my own. I can already capture and image of a canvas that I am aware of, but is there a view or canvas or something like it that always represents what is on the screen, so that a) I don't have to capture the separate views images and recompile them, and b) I can see what my native (jni) code is doing with the graphics too?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to access the "raw" framebuffer from an application.  On some devices you can get at it with sufficient permissions (e.g. the DDMS screen dump), but not even that will work on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

Um if you are using view.getRootView() then although it is a view as you were complaining about, it gets a collection of all the views within the screen so you should not need to recompile anything, at least I know I don't when I use it. Sorry don't think it would be too helpful for seeing what the code-behind is doing to on screen graphics.